# How can I get the thread id of the threads of the servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Just as the title. Google didn't give me any clue.

Edit: What I mean is to get the threads that executing the code of the servlet. Thanks.

Edit: Why I want this information, this is because when there are many threads executing, their log aggregate in a single log, and the order of log is disrupt. I want a thread id inserted at the front of each line of the log so that I can trace the activity of each thread.

Comment: This is meaningless question lacking any details. It shows utter inability to explain things and lack of respect to other's time.

Comment: I just thought the answer would be simple. Never though that you would need to know WHY I want this information. Well, now the question is edited.

Comment: @gunbuster363, you might not need to do this, if you are using java.util.logging, log4j or slf4j.

Comment: @Vinneet, yes I am using log4j, do you have any idea to seperate the log?

Comment: to distinguish the log records, you may want to do some research in your log libs, most of them has a way to tweak the output which gives you the option to show the current thread id ... however u didn't mention which lib u using

Comment: @gunbuster363, use the %t pattern.

Comment: @Vinnet, "t  Used to output the name of the thread that generated the logging event." I think is it talking about the thread that wrote the log?

Comment: @gunbuster363, yes, that would uniquely identify the thread. Most servlet containers would provide the name to the threads in the threadpool that they use, so all threads can be uniquely identified at a point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not actually a meaningful thing to ask for.

Threads don't belong to a servlet.  Rather, they belong to the web container and are used to run requests ... which at certain points involves running servlet methods.  A servlet method can of course find out what the current thread is ... but then so can any method.

It is also possible that the web container might use thread groups in a way that allows you to determine that certain threads are used for certain things.  But that would be highly implementation specific.

If that's not what you mean, then please refine your question.

---

> What I mean is to get the threads that executing the code of the servlet.

Do you mean **currently** executing the code of the servlet?

Then I think that the answer is simply - "This is not possible".

It is not possible *within a running program* for one application thread to find out what code another thread is executing.  This kind of thing can only be found using a debug agent ... while all application threads are stopped.

---

> I want a thread id inserted at the front of each line of the log so that I can trace the activity of each thread.

(Well why didn't you simply ask that in the first place??)

A log4j LoggingEvent contains the name of the thread that created the event.  You can use a `%t` in a pattern layout to include the thread name in a log file.  You could also write your own custom Appender to filter the events into different "streams" based on the event's thread name.

The thread id is not available for logging ... unless you explicitly insert it into (for example) the log message string.

Comment: @gunbuster363 - no it shouldn't.  It answers one interpretation of your question.  It's not my fault that your question / comments don't clearly state what you actually need to know.

Comment: @gunbuster363 - AFAIK, it is the thread name for the thread that created the event.  Why else would there be a `getThreadName` method in the LoggingEvent API?  You have **looked at the API javadocs** I assume ...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

in the servlet code?  That will give you the ID of the thread running the servlet's `service()` method.  Obviously many of those can be going on simultaneously.  Or do you mean something else by "id of the threads of the servlet"?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the threads in the current thread group with this code:

```
int active = Thread.activeCount();
Thread allThreads[] = new Thread[active];
active = Thread.enumerate(allThreads);
```

You can then call `getId()` for each element of the returned array. You can get fancier by first climbing to the root ThreadGroup of the current thread.

What would you want this information for?

Comment: The code contains a race condition: number of active threads can increase between activeCount() and enumerate().

Comment: The poster clearly couldn't see that the "unuseful" answers are in fact attempts to help someone who cannot even explain his own problem.

Comment: Why would I want to know the id of all the threads at once? Of course I only need the id of 1 specific thread.

Comment: @road - Yes, there is a race condition and you run the risk of missing a few threads if others were added. (I edited the code to capture the return value from `enumerate`.) I suppose a way around all that is to use `Thread.getAllStackTraces()`. The keys of the returned Map are the currently live threads. That lets the system worry about race conditions, but it seems like a lot of extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get only the currrent thread id using *Thread.currentThread().getId()*. If you want to track all the threads executing your servlet, keep a list in the request called *executedThreads* and add the current thread id to the list.